# Duplicacy in Index of Pandas Series

Tags: python, pandas, duplicates

In Pandas Series, It says that the index values must be unique and a hashable. But when Duplicate Indexes are provided, it still stores both the values, and does not delete the value corresponding to the same index previously, unlike what happens in a Dictionary in Python. Why so? Does it avoid collisions and stores both values corresponding to same Index? 
Precisely, This is my Code-

```
d=pd.Series(['Saurabh','Singh','Bazzad'],[1,2,1])
```

And the output I get when I print d is-

```
1    Saurabh
2      Singh
1     Bazzad
```

Comment: Format your question properly along with the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`index` docstring from `pandas.Series`

```
index : array-like or Index (1d)
    Values must be hashable and have the same length as `data`.
    Non-unique index values are allowed. Will default to
    RangeIndex (0, 1, 2, ..., n) if not provided. If both a dict and index
    sequence are used, the index will override the keys found in the
    dict.
```

As it mentioned there, Non-unique values are allowed.